# Is the strong exception safety guarantee with a pass-by-value argument which can throw on destruction possible?

Tags: c++, exceptions, exception-handling, error-handling

Suppose you have a type with a throwing destructor, and a function receiving it by value.
Can that operation ever provide anything better than the basic exception guarantee?
Or formulated differently, may one disregard the destruction of the argument which was passed by value when determining whether an operation has commmit-and-rollback-semantics?

```
#include <cstdlib>

struct X {
    ~X() noexcept(0) {
        if(rand()%6 == 0) throw 0;
    }
    // some state
};

void update(database db, X arg) noexcept;

X x;
update(db, x);
```

Personally, based on [the definition from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety)

> 2. **Strong exception safety**, also known as **commit or rollback semantics**: Operations can fail, but failed operations are guaranteed to have no side effects, so all data retain their original values

I don't think it's useful to describe `update` as being strongly exception-safe, even though *the function itself* cannot even throw.

I would appreciate either someone showing me the folly of my current understanding, or giving a better argument.

Comment: What if a method in the class throws and the caller decides to dispose the object?  Will the destructor still close the transaction?

Comment: Method in which class? And close what transaction? Sorry, but I'm confused now.

Comment: Well, unless a memento pattern is being used, or a database transaction is involved, I don't see how the state of the class isn't lost when the object is disposed, unless you're saying it's a stateless class.

Comment: `X` should not be stateless, so yes, that state is lost.

Comment: The question was inspired by the argument here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32049/discussion-between-loki-astari-and-deduplicator http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32061/discussion-on-answer-by-loki-astari-stack-implementation-move-semantics

Comment: In general, a throwing destructor is complete poison to all exception safety guarantees. It just gets harder by orders of magnitude.

Comment: My first thought wen reading this question that was confirmed by reading your chat is that the actual problem here is not the exception guarantee but the definition of “failure”. The function itself always either commits or rolls back but the caller might not know what it did. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with exception guarantees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really sure in retrospect, but if `update` was generic or if `X` was abstract (ex: cloned and destroyed) -- i.e., if `update` could not know anything concrete about `X`, then for all practical purposes I'd describe it as having a strong exception-safety guarantee. At the very least that's as close to a strong exception-safety guarantee you'll ever get in an abstract context without x-raying a data type.

However, `X` is concrete, so that makes this question a lot more fuzzy. I'm still tempted to say that `update` "has a strong exception safety guarantee" since it is doing everything it can possibly do to enforce it. Does that sound like crazy talk? It does to me, but I can't really put it much better.

Especially in the context of a team environment where one author implements `update` and the other implements `X`, nothing could ever provide a strong exception-safety guarantee since `X` could be modified in ways that breaks the guarantee in ways completely beyond the control of `update`. For practical purposes, I think if `update` does everything it possibly can and should to roll back its own side effects in exceptional paths, it practically provides a strong exception safety guarantee.

Otherwise the strong exception safety guarantee becomes something impractical to ever provide in so many scenarios. Things could change outside the function's control. Things could be abstract in ways beyond the function's knowledge. The whole guarantee would be almost impossible to provide anywhere. In that case might we say that the strong exception guarantee of `update` propagates a responsibility to `X` to comply, or is it `update` that is required to know how `X` will be implemented at all times? I don't know. This is all very impractical either way, and I don't like impracticalities.

So I'm gonna go with the crude, yeah, *"`update` is exception-safe, but `X` gone fubar and messed up everything. It's not `update's` fault at least. Don't sue the author of update! Sue the author of `X`!"*. I'd like to describe `X` as simply being fubar here, and `update` as possibly providing a strong exception safety guarantee which is being screwed by the fact that `X` is fubar. That is, unless there is a very hard interface-level understanding that `X's` destructor is designed to throw, in which case I have no idea how to describe it except as a "big problem". I think we need some fine print and disclaimers to come with these guarantees. *update provides a strong exception-safety guarantee provided that [...]. No refunds if this is not the case!*

This is like a philosophical question to me, interesting to think about but maybe one with no perfect answer. And what are guarantees anyway? Can we guarantee anything? I might guarantee that drinking beer would make me drunk and that could seem true all the time, but what if an extraterrestrial intervenes and uses some kind of alien technology which makes me sober no matter how much I drink? I can't *guarantee* that this won't happen. I can only say that this is highly improbable and that if such event were to happen, I would be powerless against it. I did my part. I drank my beer. I'm supposed to get drunk. I strongly guarantee it. But it's not for certain. There's always some probability, however astronomically remote, that the guarantee might not hold true. How about thread safety? Well, what if the alien spaceship comes and zaps our hardware and rearranges instructions in memory such that a formely thread-safe function is now no longer thread-safe at runtime? I can't guarantee that this won't happen. But I will guarantee thread-safety regardless without even going into such fine print about alien space ships, because it makes people feel nice and reassured, and what I'm saying is that I'm doing everything within my power and knowledge to enforce that guarantee.

Descartes once said, "I think therefore, I am." How does he know? What if he isn't? He could be an "am not" but perhaps "nots" can "think". I don't even know if I exist. What does thinking even mean anyway? It's like a word people use to describe some process that appears to go on introspectively and appears as though we, who may not even exist, are making decisions.

What if we are all just bits and bytes on some machine? Like that blonde or brunette in the Matrix. By the way, how can a blonde or especially brunette be stored in such a small stream of characters? Are they like UTF2048? It was some kind of alien stream of characters but there didn't appear to be too many unique characters. Perhaps it's some kind of function call. Anyway, I'm not sure we can guarantee anything. It's all relative to what we believe to be true.

Comment: "So "exception safety" of any sort and "throwing destructor" should probably never be combined in the same sentence. They are, for all practical purposes, mutually exclusive." +1, can't argue with that logic. If you think you can, you aren't being logical.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the original question. The problem here is that arg will destroy exactly on function exit. The function will have no chance to catch this. If the function has done something, it will not have a chance to roll it back.

Comment: @NirFriedman The issue is somewhat a matter of perspective. My argument is that a function should be considered to have a strong exception safety guarantee independent of the side effects outside of its control. Here `update` cannot possibly do anything about it, so I'd considered `update` (provided it swallows any exceptions and reverses any side effects within its control) to provide a strong exception safety guarantee.

Comment: @NirFriedman Exception-safety guarantees have more to do with interface requirements than implementation details. The fact that the destructor of `X` here would make it impossible for it to be exception-safe in, say, `std::vector`, does not affect the exception-safety guarantees of `std::vector`, since `std::vector` would not be able to do anything about it. It does affect the exception-safety of the code in general, but not the exception-safety guarantees of these interfaces.

Comment: I'm not really following. Are you claiming that because X is destroyed just after function execution, update itself is not throwing in that case?

Comment: @NirFriedman Here it's impossible, if you just analyze the code, for it to gracefully recover during an exceptional path if `update` throws, since that could lead to the random odds during stack unwind that the destructor of `X` also throws (which would inevitably lead to `std::terminate`). But the question seems to have to do with whether we can consider `update` to provide a strong exception safety guarantee anyway, and I'd strongly suggest "yes".

Comment: @NirFriedman Consider functions that invoke no side effects. `Something flip(Something) {...}`... we would say `flip` here has no side effects provided its implementation causes none, and is a pure function, since we're analyzing the logic of the function. But imagine if `Something`, on construction/destruction, triggered a global side effect... even then, I would argue, `f` is a pure function -- we don't analyze the construction/destruction side effects in the context of determining whether a function is pure, since it's outside the function's control.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of that. Bottom line: update does something, arg is destroyed on exit and throws, which update is unable to catch. An exception has escaped update, and the state of the world is different than it was prior to calling update. So update does not offer the strong guarantee.

Comment: @NirFriedman From that perspective, it becomes difficult to analyze the exception safety of anything without knowing every last implementation detail of everything involved... which is why we would never be able to say, in a generic context, that something like `std::vector` is exception-safe. We tend to describe things like exception safety and side effects guarantees in the context of what a function has control over.

Comment: @NirFriedman Imagine `std::swap`... we describe it as swapping the contents of two objects... but if we analyzed the implementation details, something being swapped could define a move constructor in a way that doesn't do that, it might draw a picture of Jessica Alba on the screen. But that shouldn't impact the way we describe what `swap` does, since `swap` is logically implemented to swap two objects -- if something else happens, it would be outside its control.

Comment: It is difficult to analyze exception safety :-). Again, I think you are being vague: "what a function has control over". Meaning, inside the body of the function, and therefore disincluding the current case? A technicality, but a valid one. By your argument, push_back when it has filled the capacity of the vector should just be able to move construct its elements into the new storage, but it does not do this.

Comment: @NirFriedman Perhaps we could refine it a bit... but my basic case is that if you consider weird constructor/destructor exception behavior into the mix, then especially generic contexts could provide no exception-safety guarantees whatsoever, since they cannot possibly anticipate every possible use case.

Comment: @NirFriedman From a team-oriented perspective, you could do everything correct inside `update`, within your control, to provide a strong-exception safety guarantee... rolling back all side effects directly caused within the function, and the functions it calls. And perhaps `X` could be implemented in originally in a way that doesn't throw in its dtor. But then any person could come along, change `X`, and actually invalidate the exception-safety guarantees of `update`. That's why I don't think `X's` destructor behavior should be accounted for in this scenario.

Comment: @NirFriedman It would be impossible to stabilize any documented interface guarantees in general if we start considering possible side effects that are caused or could be caused by constructors/destructors beyond an ordinary construction/destruction semantic. A function that invokes the expression, `a + b`, is supposed to add two things, if someone overloads operators there for `a/b` to format a hard drive, that doesn't mean it invalidates the documentation and behavior of this function.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct conclusion, it doesn't become less correct by being unpleasant. In the case of vector, it's illegal for it's contained type's destructor to ever throw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902006/may-the-elements-in-a-stdvector-have-a-throwing-destructor. I understand your "team-oriented" approach, but frankly it's looking at it from a perspective of fairness rather than correctness.

Comment: @NirFriedman That's very true -- but I'm trying to come from a practical perspective. I just think it's too difficult to make interface guarantees about anything, whether side effects or exception-safety, if we start analyzing the logic outside of a function's control (like in the `operator+` case above).

Comment: From a practical perspective, if you depend on update having the strong guarantee, you're in for a bad time. The real answer is to document requirements in the case of generics (as vector does), and check your downstream dependencies when you change concrete types. The practical thing is not to say something gives the strong guarantee when it doesn't because that perspective gives a cleaner division of responsibilities between update and X.

Comment: @NirFriedman Consider thread-safety guarantees in another. How can we ever document them in a stable interface, if we consider the implementation details of ctors/dtors/copy assignment, e.g., as potentially causing external side effects and dtors and throwing and so forth?

Comment: @NirFriedman Yeah, that's true.. in this case we do have foresight of what `X` does in advance.. but I'm also thinking in terms of the stability of documentation. I think you're right, the very best way is to document that `update` provides strong exception-safety guarantees provided that `X` does not throw in the destructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33240/discussion-between-ike-and-nir-friedman).

Comment: My preferred interpretation is simply that throwing in a destructor is undefined behavior, and what exception guarantees a function has are all based on the implicit assumption that no undefined behavior occurs (indeed, everything in the language makes that assumption). If undefined behavior can include formatting your hard drive, it can certainly include violating the otherwise correct exception guarantees of everything else in the program.

Comment: @lxrec That's a nice way to look at it. A difficulty I'm seeing is that every noexcept function which accepts anything by value would have to kind of assert that its exception-safety guarantees only apply provided that the types of its arguments do not throw on destruction. It would be much simpler to take that for granted, and assert that a function that provides a strong exception-safety guarantee can only do so provided that the destructors of its parameter types will not throw (and continue not to do so indefinitely).

Comment: @Ixrec That may be your preferred interpretation, but throwing from a destructor is not ub in general, that's simply a fact.

Answer (score -1):

Technically speaking, it can perhaps provide the strong exception guarantee. Meaningfully, it can only provide the strong exception guarantee in the trivial case where it does nothing.

Herb Sutter talks about a similar (and more intuitive case) where a function takes an argument by value that has a throwing copy constructor. You can label such a function noexcept. Technically, the exception occurs in the "glue" between the calling code and the called function, not inside the function itself. That's the case here as well. Since the exception is not technically thrown inside update, you could (perhaps) argue that update itself does not generate the error and therefore can offer the strong exception guarantee.

Practically speaking, if update does anything, then calling it (and doing nothing else) can lead to the state of the world changing and an exception being thrown, breaking the strong exception guarantee.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33330/discussion-on-answer-by-nir-friedman-is-the-strong-exception-safety-guarantee-wi).